# different type of screen sizes with 4 rectangular shapes in view

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, autolayout

I have a bit of an issue here. I'm developing this app and in every device size, it looks good except the iPhone 5. I try to look online for tutorials about auto constrain but none of the covers how to make those 4 rectangles behave in the iPhone 5 screen. Any idea how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image: Iphone 6 simulator]
iphone 6 sim

[image: iPhone 5 simulator]
iphone 5 sim

iphone 5

Comment: I'm assuming your "Composite Score" is in one view, your Ad is in 2nd view, your "details" are in 3rd view, and your Gender and Age Groups are segmented controls in 4th view? If so, do you want to decrease the vertical spacing in the "details" section?

Comment: Is the second pic an iPhone 5 pic? What is your problem? All content does not fit in the screen?

Comment: @RobertoSampaio Yes sir

Comment: @DonMag They are all separates view. the sit ups,aerobic,etc they are in one big view (like the 4 of them are in the same view) I just want the same output as the iphone 6 screenshoot in the iphone 5.

Comment: Is the content fits on iPhone SE? Does't fit in any iOS version?

Comment: it fit in all other iOS version except on the iPhone SE.

Comment: *"I just want the same output as the iphone 6 screenshoot in the iPhone 5"* Well, you cannot get that. The screens have different heights, so you need to decrease some of the empty vertical space.

Comment: I agree with @DonMag. You need to decrease the height, or insert everything in a UIScrollView. Maybe you can use UIStackView in order to fit everything in a good way

Comment: Im mainly concern with  the right labels on the iphone 5 (ex "Push...." and "Aerobic ...." ) how do I get those views to have the same width as (Sit Ups and Abdominal) . I

Comment: What does your layout look like? Are you using Stack View(s) to layout those elements? Fixed widths? Constraints between them?